# Minimizing area and maximizing volume, under constraints using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, operations-research

### Context

I'm in year 12 of school, and for our curriculum, we have to write a 12-page thesis on any mathematical subject. Since I picked maths for Higher Level the maths has to be commensurate for that level (and sometimes a tad bit above).

### The problem I am facing

For my thesis, I'm working with Lagrange multipliers for one of the parts but every single time I try to solve the equations which I got from rearranging so that they are equal to the multiplier phi, I'm either getting a complex volume (function 1 = function 2) or an unsolvable function (function 2 = function 3).

### My work:

Three functions using Lagrange multipliers
[image]

Setting Eq. 1 and Eq. 2 (accidently wrote eq. 3 on paper) equal to each other to solve for them V by substituting h= (3V)/(ab)

[image]

Equating (2) and (3)

$$ \sqrt{h^2 + \frac{a^2}{h} }+ \frac{\sqrt{h^2 + \frac{a^2}{h}}}{\sqrt{h^2 + \frac{b^2}{h}}} = 4ab$$

### Reference

Any and all help would be much appreciated. I'm using [this thesis](https://www.clastify.com/ia/maths/5fba8e3bf4fda55746067a1b) as a reference (bottom part is about Lagrange's multipliers).

Comment: Using so many links in a question requires anyone who might want to answer to open all your four links in separate tabs.  Internet links die over time.

Comment: it said that I'm not allowed to embed links yet in a question. Im sorry though

Comment: I'll do that for you; just try to save links for things like graphs, that are difficult to include any other way.

Comment: Alright, ill do that next time. Thanks for letting me know! Is there a way you can change it however, as in should I give edit access etc.?

Comment: No, you will be able to embed in little time: once you have a wee bit more rep.

Comment: Ah alright, thanks for letting me know

Comment: It's going to take me time, because some of what you want to add are images I must save from respective sites.

Comment: You may find this video I made interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=js277PnBccI

(Shameless plug)

Comment: Well well, the second image is too large to be uploaded

Comment: And the first needs to be accessed online.   In the future, Mjstc, please transcribe such passes you need to post, wrt the first link, into the post.

Comment: Here is what I did, the first two images I pasted and the last one which I couldn't, I copied what I read as the conclusion of the derivation in the third link you had attached

Comment: Holy smokes, Thank you guys for all the help. Just a question to the transcription, does it use a programming language or is there a mathematics interface (similar to wolfram alpha)

Comment: It uses something called mathjax.  To make it work you enclose the equation in two dollars at the beginning and end. More complicated syntax can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And, for formatting the post, html/mark down is used

Comment: Calculus of variations

Comment: @RyanHowe How would I go forth with completing it using Lagrange's multipliers similar to how it is done in the reference website since the calculus of variations seems a bit too above what we learn? Or is there a way to easily use calc. of var. to solve this?

Comment: @MjstcMaze You create a function from the volume and subtract off the surface area and maximize that. This should be moved to Operations Research stack probably.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I'm sorry but since I dont have too much experience with this level of calculus would it be possible to send me a resource which explains this?